# Undefined is not an object(evaluating'_react3.default.PropType.shape')

Tags: react-native, admob

I've done a lot of research on the subject. I have not reached a conclusion. How can I solve this problem. Thank you.

http://prntscr.com/jesy2n

package.json

```
{
  "name": "OlsunBuSefer",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.3",
    "react-native-admob": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the version of the package that you're using `react-native-admob` has not been updated since late.

The **PropTypes** have been moved to a separate package since `React v15.5` as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

You can check the example in their [RNAdMobBanner.js](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/blob/de918032fce21b47a8c51ca12adccd4680e364ea/RNAdMobBanner.js#L68) of version `1.x`

`bannerSize: React.PropTypes.string,`

**Workaround:**

You need to update the package using `yarn add react-native-admob@next` to use their version `^2.0.0-beta.5`

Comment: thanks man. Updated react-native-admob ^2.0.0-beta.5. but show error. 

RNGADBannerView does not exist. how I do now. ? Thanks.

Comment: Check the installation [here](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/230) to setup. There is something missing during the installation.

Comment: If I can reach a solution, I will share it here.

Comment: The solution is simple, you need to `link` your dependencies correctly, either by `react-native link` or manual linking if it fails.

Comment: Although I have not worked for 4 days, no solution has yet been found. What is the problem. I can not guess. Thank you for comments.

Comment: Hi guys. Solution solved with android studio updated. Thanks.